# In my AWS AppSync request resolver. I want to return an object with some properties and empty array as a value

Tags: aws-appsync

I am using an AWS AppSync pipeline function. In my request mapping template, I want to do the distribution on the basis of some condition.

I am setting a variable distribution. The variable distribution having properties with an empty array.

Example:

request.vtl

1: Initially, I am setting up a variable distribution

```
#set($distribution={
  "NotAnswered": [],
  "NeedsWork": [],
  "AlmostThere": [],
  "Mastered": []
})
```

2: Processing and assigning the distribution.

NOTE: If there is not items simply returning the step 1 distribution.

```
#foreach($itemScore in $itemScores)
  #if($itemScore.score == 100)
    $distribution.Mastered.add($itemScore.itemId)
  #elseif($itemScore.score >= 80)
    $distribution.AlmostThere.add($itemScore.itemId)
  #else
    $distribution.NeedsWork.add($itemScore.itemId)
  #end
#end
```

3: $util.toJson($distribution)

In my response mapping template, I am trying to return the required format.

response.vtl

4: returning the result

```
#set($metadata={})
#set($distribution = {})
$util.qr($distribution.put('notAnswered', $result.NotAnswered.size()))
$util.qr($distribution.put('NeedsWork', $result.NeedsWork.size()))
$util.qr($distribution.put('NeedsWork', $result.NeedsWork.size()))
$util.qr($distribution.put('Mastered', $result.Mastered.size()))
$util.qr($metadata.put('distribution', $distribution))
$util.qr($term.put('metadata', $metadata))
```

Getting the error 
"message": "Unsupported element '$[NotAnswered]'."

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide the complete code of each mapping template? I might have a guess but i need to see the whole code.

Comment: Thanks, I found the solution.

Comment: I am attaching my resolver to an empty data source.  In my request.vtl instead of returning the distribution in JSON format($util.toJson($distribution)), we should return like this {
    "version": "2017-02-28",
    "payload": $utils.toJson($distribution)
}